# Use MVC View in Angular

Tags: angular, model-view-controller

I have a .NET Core app which has a method returning a view.

Is it possible to call this method from an angular application using a standard http.get and open the returned view in a separate window?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Use `target="_blank"` for new window

```
<a href="https://your/requested/mvc/endpoint" target="_blank">go here</a>
```

And in href use requested endpoint.

Comment: He wants to open view in a separate window. Moreover, he wants to open asp.net  page instead of SPA. So it is 100% valid.

Comment: I did think of this approach but I need to post a jwt token for authentication, hence my question of using http.get instead. Maybe there is another approach that would allow the token to be used?